# What tall orange flowering plants is this?

Tags: identification, flowers

This plant emerged mid spring and flowered mid summer, zone 7. I believe it self seeded from the year before, but I'm not sure. It grew in the community garden plot that I inherited. What is it?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Answer (score 2):

That's an annual sunflower known as either Mexican Sunflower or by it's botanical name, Tithonia. They're large plants and tend to have a lot of flowers over the summer. It's a  good pollinator plant as well. As for caring for your plant, there's not a whole lot you have to do other than keep it watered. Wikipedia has a good [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithonia) on the genus.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much. Any idea how I can narrow in on the species or variety?

Comment: Some searching leads me to believe that it is rotundifolia

Comment: It's probably from the variety 'Torch', which is the most common one in the trade. I'm not sure if that variety comes true from seed, but it should have most of Torch's height and width characteristics. You could have more next year if you kept some seeds this fall.